# Is it possible to get the java bean value in jsp that has no action mapping in struts config?

Tags: jsp, struts2, action

I would like to know if there is any way I can retrieve the Java bean value in JSP page that has no mapping in struts config.

I tried to set the variable using bean and retrieve it using property attribute, but of no use.

```
<s:bean var="item" name="com.store.items"> <s:set property value= "%{item.getuniqueID}"/> </s:bean>
```

Comment: i tried to set the variable using bean and retrieve it using property attribute. but of no use. <s:bean var="item" name="com.store.items"> <s:set property value= "%{item.getuniqueID}"/> </s:bean>

Comment: i resolved it using jsp scriptlets itself

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is! You can simply add an instance of the bean and its `getters` and `setters` in your action class. The bean will be created from the fields that you have in the `JSP`. In fact, if you have a multitude of properties to be added in the `action class`, it is advisable to use a bean instance instead of native properties. This will result in less complex `action` classes.

```
UserBean bean = new UserBean();
//Getters and setters
```

You can fetch the value of these properties by using `.` with the name of the instance. e.g. `<s:property value="bean.name"/>`